# how to convert .msg file to PDF using perl

Tags: perl

How to convert .msg file to PDf using perl (or) any option to conver .msg file to html using perl

Comment: What is the `.msg` file from, and what do its contents look like?

Comment: .msg file is outlook file, you can drag from outlook to desktop. You will get the .msg file, just double clicking the file you can view the message.

Answer (score 2):

Converting to PDF is the easy part.

Reading the .msg file will be the hard part, as it's a proprietary binary format. There is a detailed description (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc463912(v=exchg.80).aspx) but all OLE-based formats take a good bit of work to puzzle out data extraction.

The specification isn't hugely clear (most MS ones take some work to grasp) but it looks like it's based on the same compound structure as Office documents, in which case `OLE::Storage_Lite` will be able to manage the low-level file management. Essentially these formats all allow multiple streams of data within a single file, and it looks like .msg files are the same.

Years back, I did have to extract stuff from MS EXchange, and the strategy I used was to write a C++ class that used the MIME API, which allows RTF to be read for a message direct from the server. You can do something similar using `Win32::OLE`, but in my experience its error handling was somewhat sensitive to network performance issues. The RTF will then be easy to render into PDF, because at least you have a representation you can work with.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I can able to convert the .msg to .mime. Can any one know how to extract the .mime contents in to rtf(the mime file contains all the information). I have used [link](http://www.matijs.net/) to convert to mime

Comment: @user831025 That's a big step forward. The module I've used most for this is MIME::tools on CPAN, which contains a MIME::Parser. Bear in mind that MIME is just content-packaging framework, so you'll still need to get the stuff out from there. IIRC, it's easy to get text and often RTF, sometimes HTML, so you may need to use RTF::Parser to get HTML. That is probably the best starting point for PDF generation if you want to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try PDF::Writer. Probably you need to print .msg using PDF print driver.

Comment: I have tryed with msgconvert.pl [link](http://www.matijs.net/) i can able to convert .mime file. It is possible to convert .mime to pdf. If .msg file have attachement, it is too difficulat to convert using PDF::Writer

Comment: [http://search.cpan.org/~jhannah/PDF-TextBlock-0.04/lib/PDF/TextBlock.pm](http://search.cpan.org/~jhannah/PDF-TextBlock-0.04/lib/PDF/TextBlock.pm)    and [http://search.cpan.org/dist/PDF-API2-Simple/lib/PDF/API2/Simple.pm](http://search.cpan.org/dist/PDF-API2-Simple/lib/PDF/API2/Simple.pm) these may work out for you